# Bat file to copy a file everyday with the time stamp

Tags: batch-file, timestamp, backup

I want to create a .bat file to create a daily backup of a file. This should also update the file name with the date or time. How can create this file? I ve tried a lot of different ways.. mcopy, xcopy.. etc. somehow.. it does'nt work.

Comment: on linux you could use *cronetab* to let the script get called every day... than you could do it with `cp source destination`

Comment: Show us what you've tried and how, specifically, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this by using the task scheduler like this:

```
schtasks /create /sc DAILY /tn Backup /tr C:\backup.bat
```

*Note:* Type `schtasks /create /?` for more options.

You can rename the file with the date by using this:

```
ren C:\file.txt *. && ren C:\file. *%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (sett.txt) do set ok=%%i
if %ok%==%date% (goto end) else (     
xcopy "file target" "file destination"
echo %date%>sett.txt
echo %date%---files copied successfully>>info.txt
)
:end
exit
```

Copy this into a batch file and type in your file target and destination.Then make a shortcut to this file in the startup folder.It will copy your file every day until the batch file/shortcut is deleted.

this  file will create 2 text documents in the same folder as the batch file don't touch the sett.txt file.but in the info.txt you will have information about when did the files last copied.

hope it helps! :D